# Properly use 'next' paramater in URL, Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, redirect, django-models

Python/Django newbie here. 
I am using decorator `@login_required(login_url='/login/')` to 3 different views. I have multiple such views(think services that website offer) which can be accessed only if you are logged in. 
When I click on service button, the URL formed is something like this: `domain/login/?next=/<service_name>/` 
How do I use the `?next=<service_name>` to redirect back to service that was originally called? Currently I am sent back to homepage, because that's what my Login view does.

Comment: here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required it says your login page wil receive the current absolute path in the query string e.g. `?next=<service_name>`. so you can use that information and redirect

Comment: @Pynchia Hi, I tried to follow this but Django docs are sometimes very hard to follow for newbies. How do I use next to redirect in my view?

Comment: you need to redirect in your login view. Look for info on how to use/inherit`generic.RedirectView`. Are you using Class Based Views? If so, are you using this fundamental tool? http://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: Yes, I understand but how do I capture the url and redirect? Thanks for replying.

Comment: the url is in the `next` url variable. Access it with `request.GET.get('next', None)` then `return redirect`.. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your login view, just do this:

```
def login(request):
    """
    Check for login and store the result in login_successful
    """
    path = request.GET.get("next")
    if login_successful:
        if path:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(path)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(your_earlier_path)
```